# Can we use Python 4's end keyword in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, auto-indent

Because of my ancient animation pipeline, I am stuck with python 2.7. I saw that python 4 will have an end keyword which can already be used in python 3 with pyend (https://pypi.org/project/pyend/).
I am using that in some python 3 projects already and it's pretty cool.

However, the pypi page states "Requires: Python >=3.7". Now my question is, does that mean that pyend itself needs Python 3.7 or newer to run on but it can be used on older python code or can it only be used on code that is >=3.7? I have tried with some python 2 code and it seems to be working fine but I would rather be sure before I switch.

Comment: Based on the release date of this package, and me never hearing about python4 and the weirdness of having an `end` keyword in python, I assume this package is an April Fools Day joke

Comment: Good joke, OP. I really enjoyed reading that package's github

Comment: @Samathingamajig: Please note that April Fool's Day is culture-specific. For example, in Spain and Hispanic culture, the equivalent day is December, 28th, not April, 1st. In other cultures, something like this doesn't exist at all. So, it is perfectly possible for someone not to recognize an April Fool's Day joke for the simple reason that they may not even know what that is and may have never heard of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99% sure this package is an [April Fools Day joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day) since I've never heard of any features of Python 4 and including `end` seems to go against Python's philosophy.

The [first](https://pypi.org/project/pyend/0.0.1/) [two](https://pypi.org/project/pyend/0.0.2/) releases mention nothing of Python 4. Also, take note of this paragraph, "Does it stop there?"

> It sure does not! It also uses tabs instead of spaces for indentation. Because using tabs instead of spaces is much better. However, if you hold the opinion that your pristine code should look the same everywhere, you can set the `--convert-tabs-to-spaces-despite-tabs-being-objectively-better-than-spaces flag`, which will convert indentation tabs into 11 spaces. Should you not like 11 spaces for indentation and you would rather enforce your personal taste onto everyone else, you can set the `--use-this-many-spaces-per-tab-cuz-as-a-spacist-i-want-uniformity-but-i-dont-want-the-default` flag to whatever your heart desires.

That flag is definitely a joke.

Another thing is the release date and versioning. Version `1.4.23` came out today, April 1st, after just having `0.0.1`-`0.0.3`

[image]

That being said, to answer the question is that since `pyend` is a command you run in the terminal, and not something you import, it can *probably* handle all python3.x code, it can *almost definitely* handle all python3.7+ code, and it *probably cannot* handle python2.x code. The syntax for Python 2 is different from Python 3 (the most common example is that `print` is a statement in v2 but a function in v3).